# Как лучше установить связи?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть образец. Образец может поступить от разных лабораторий. При этом образцу должен быть присвоен префикс. Один и тот же префикс может быть присвоен к разным лабораториям. Классическая связь многие ко многим: у одной лаборатории может быть множество префиксов, а один префикс может быть у множества лабораторий.

Каждый образец нумеруется цифрой в отдельном поле `sample_number` таблицы `образец`. При этом в пределах каждого префикса не может быть повторов номеров. Т.е. префикс и номер образца - уникальный индекс. Также для каждого образца следует иметь возможность установить, от какой лаборатории он поступил.

А теперь вопрос - как лучше организовать связи? Понимаю, что в идеале следовало бы связь тянуть от таблицы многие ко многим, но так нельзя...

**Вариант 1**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вариант 2**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вариант 3** - ???

Comment: Префикс не является сущностью. Он является составной частью атрибута Образец.ПолныйНомер. Так что схема должна состоять из двух таблиц и единственной связи между ними. А на совокупность полей (Префикс, Номер) - накладывается требование уникальности. Теоретически есть ситуации, когда имеет смысл выделение префиксов в отдельную таблицу, при этом в таблицу Образцов записывается ID записи из таблицы префиксов. Но Вам ещё нужно доказать себе, что у Вас именно такая ситуация.

Comment: @Akina Вынести всё же префиксы нужно в отдельную таблицу. И описать возможные комбинации тоже нужно. Всё это для исключения ошибки "оператора" - чтобы не выбрал для лаборатории префикс, который никак с ней не связан. Когда лабораторий\префиксов много, это особенно важно и актуально. Так что 4 таблицы в данной ситуации нужная вещь. Но вопрос в том, как всё же тянуть связи - от таблицы Префикс и Лаборатория к таблице Образец. Или от таблицы Префикс_Образец тянуть связи (две)? Правильнее, кажется, первый вариант...

Comment: Да не вопрос... выносите. Только Вы опять делаете всё ту же ошибку - пара словарей-таблиц Префиксы и ПрефиксЛаборатория являются элементами шаблона, т.е. они связаны с таблицей Лаборатории, но **НЕ** связаны с таблицей Образцы (хотя и используются при формировании уникального номера с префиксом при создании записи в этой таблице). Так что правильной с Вашими поправками будет первая схема, из которой удалена связь Префикс-Образец.

Comment: @Akina Это что-то странное для меня... Т.е. если бы я, например, для образцов ещё указывал дополнительно страну и хранил бы список стран в отдельной таблице-справочнике, то  я НЕ должен был бы устанавливать связь один ко многим между Страны и Образцы?

Comment: Аналогия неверна. Связка (Префикс-ПрефиксЛаборатория)->(Лаборатория) формирует эталонный экземпляр свойства Префикс. Когда Вы создаёте экземпляр Образца, Вы делаете **копию** эталонного образца, а потом индивидуализируете его, добавляя уникальную номерную часть. В то время как в приведённой аналогии Вы не делаете копию какой-то страны с последующей её корректировкой. Опять же подумайте - что будет с Вашей схемой, если через некоторое время некоей лаборатории будет запрещено использовать некий префикс? Удалите связку? всё рассыплется... Оставите? а как тогда задать запрет...

Comment: @Akina Но ведь если использовать предложенный вами вариант (удалить связь Префикс->Образец), то чтобы запретить какой-то лаборатории использовать некий префикс (который использовался ранее), придётся удалить из таблицы Префикс_Лаборатория связь многие ко многим. Если вновь понадобится разрешить лаборатории использовать некий префикс - потребуется добавить опять запись в таблицу Префикс_Лаборатория. Но можно ведь не удалять, а ввести в этой таблице поле Доступность, где хранить 1 - можно выбрать комбинацию. И 2, если нельзя. И если оставить связь Префикс->Образец, запросы будут короче. Нет?

Comment: Какая разница - удалять или помечать как недоступное? суть-то одна... главное - изменение шаблона не может даже теоретически иметь какое-то влияние на существующие данные, что возможно лишь при отсутствии связи.

Comment: @Akina пожалуй, вы правы. Множество раз перечитал всё и вроде бы понял. Спасибо. Не будете оформлять как ответ?

Comment: *Не будете оформлять как ответ?* Чтобы с того ответа был толк - нужно скопипастить в него почти всё вот это обсуждение. А тогда смысл?

Comment: Подскажите ещё одно, пожалуйста. Каждой Лаборатории-Поставщику могут оказываться разные дополнительные услуги. И для каждой такой лаборатории стоимость этих услуг может быть разной. Раньше бы я это сделал так - http://i.imgur.com/srjUzC2.png . Теперь же, если переосмыслить, получится вот так - http://i.imgur.com/imnWTdW.png. Верно ли я понимаю?

Comment: СтоимостьУслуги - это атрибут связи ЛабораторияУслуга.

Comment: @Akina Выходит, что вот так - http://i.imgur.com/3QoYT2k.png ? Иначе ведь не отследить по какой цене когда-то было что-то заказано.

Comment: Ну вот, опять... шаблон (текущая цена услуги по прейскуранту) и экземпляр (по какой цене была получена заказанная услуга).  И ведь не факт, что они равны, даже если даты совпадают - может, за опт исполнитель дал 5% скидки...

Comment: @Akina Действительно... Если этого не происходило или не представляется сейчас в будущем, не значит, что такого не может случиться. Выходит, связь нужно убрать - http://i.imgur.com/1SifGbw.png. Отдаю должное, если не восхищаюсь, умением вашим чётно и однозначно разбивать всё на сущности и определять что есть что. Пожалуй, стоит мне почитать что-то серьёзное по проектированию